# Can i create new object by define new keyword from object literal?

Tags: javascript, object, jsobject

I have created an object by defining the 'new' keyword from the object literal. But the problem is I can't access that object without looping. so is there any way to access that object?

```js
const animal = {
  animalDetails: function(a, b) {
    this.a = a
    this.b = b
  },

  animalOutPut: function() {
    console.log(this.a, this.b)
  },
}

// passing output by parameter ................................................................

animal.animalDetails('ape', 'Baboon')

// Call the object animal ................................................................

animal.animalOutPut()

// Create New Object Fruits from animal object literal ................................................................
let fruits = new animal.animalDetails('Apple', 'Blackberries')


for (let v in fruits) {
  console.log(fruits[v])
}
```

Comment: `console.log(fruits.a)`

Comment: You want a class, not an object.

Comment: Thanks :). But I want to know that is a lack of this way of writing object constructor instead of using class? I'm just trying to understand for which deficit we are using CLASS syntax.

Comment: `animalOutput` is not a property of the object created using `new animal.animalDetails()`, it's a property of `animal`. You need to learn about prototypes. Classes handle these details automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You want a class

```
class animal {

  constructor(a, b){

    this.a = a;
    this.b = b;
 
  }

  animalOutput(){

    console.log(this.a, this.b);

  }

}
```

You can easily define the class `let tiger = new animal("tiger", "grrr")`
A class allows you to create multiple of them as well, much more useful then an object.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks for your nice answer. But I was curious about it :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to loop it. You can access the `a` and `b` properties just like you can with `animal`.

You can't use `fruits.animalOutput()` because `animalOutput` is a property only of the `animal` object. This object is not a prototype of objects created using `new animalDetails()`, so there's no inheritance.

```js
const animal = {
  animalDetails: function(a, b) {
    this.a = a
    this.b = b
  },

  animalOutPut: function() {
    console.log(this.a, this.b)
  },
}

// passing output by parameter ................................................................

animal.animalDetails('ape', 'Baboon')

// Call the object animal ................................................................

animal.animalOutPut()

// Create New Object Fruits from animal object literal ................................................................
let fruits = new animal.animalDetails('Apple', 'Blackberries')

console.log(fruits.a, fruits.b);
```

Comment: Yes animalOutput is not a part of the fruits object absolutely right but I'm thinking how to bring for-in loop to the fruits object value :(. where is it comes from? I know about class but I want to know about this ghosting behavior :)

Comment: That's how you loop over any object's properties. There's nothing special about using it here.

Comment: But you said in the question that you can't access it without looping. I've shown in my answer that this isn't true. It's just like any other object -- if you know the property name, you just use `.`.